# How to make a cross origin Http post request with modified User-Agent header javascript or php?

Tags: php, javascript, http, header, user-agent

I want to read plain/text from an Https server. I have tried various codes php and JavaScripts, but to no success. I tried to send a request using Fiddle HTTP Debugging software with modified user-Agent value and I got a response from the server. When I used JavaScript, the browser Firefox and Chrome always change the user-Agent parameter to default agent. I never got anything from the server.

-Send https POST to mydomain.code.com
-User-Agent must be 'myAgent 1.0'

NOTE: am sending the request from another domain.

What is the best approach for this? Please I need some help here! thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get around the cross domain restrictions (see [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), at least on the browser side. You'll need to use a proxy of some sort. There is a good description along with sample code [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I can connect to the server but, I guess the proxy send as GET method instead of POST -Reason: When I use Fiddler to send the request using 'POST' I get the correct response, but when I use 'GET' I get same error with the php  proxy "error=2;buffer=;time= "  here is a link to my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/zityiR4t)

Comment: Well, your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS are in the wrong format for one thing. You want ampersands instead of semicolons. Besides that looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The API requires a string in this format. This format works well with Fiddler. I have a feeling the request is sent as a 'GET' instead of 'POST'.

Comment: I found a solution: but not php cURL, I had to go with socket HTTPS, SSL via php. I built my header and all works fine now. Thanks